# Can't connect to FTP server using FTPHook in Apache Airflow

Tags: ftp, airflow

I'm trying to use the FTPHook class in Apache Airflow. The following is a test code using `ftp.gnu.org` as an example:

```
from airflow.contrib.hooks.ftp_hook import FTPHook
hook = FTPHook('gnu')
print(hook.list_directory(''))
```

This code returns the error:

```
{base_hook.py:84} INFO - Using connection to: id: gnu. Host: ftp.gnu.org, Port: None, Schema: None, Login: None, Password: None, extra: {}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(hook.list_directory(''))
  File "/home/ubuntu/.anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/ftp_hook.py", line 127, in list_directory
    conn.cwd(path)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/ftplib.py", line 631, in cwd
    return self.voidcmd(cmd)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/ftplib.py", line 278, in voidcmd
    return self.voidresp()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/ftplib.py", line 251, in voidresp
    resp = self.getresp()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/ftplib.py", line 246, in getresp
    raise error_perm(resp)
ftplib.error_perm: 530 Please login with USER and PASS.
```

However, if we put this line of code `hook.get_conn().login()` before the `print` function, everything works. Is this a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the Apache Airflow community in Slack, we could solve the problem by setting proper username and password in the Airflow GUI platform. Although I was trying to connect as an anonymous user, it is necessary to set *username = 'anonymous'* and *password = 'anonymous@'*. This seems to be the default settings from *ftplib*, as can be seem in the first example of the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html), but Airflow changes these values to *None* if you leave them empty.